# Convert array of delimited strings to variables

Tags: php, arrays, ini, text-parsing, delimited

I need to convert all items in array to variables like:

```
$item[0] = "apple=5";
$item[1] = "banana=7";
$item[2] = "orange=8";
```

And I want to convert it to this:

```
$apple = 5;
$banana = 7;
$orange = 8;
```

Like normal variables. Is it possible?

Comment: What's your source format? I suppose you don't actually define this array manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a silly thing to do, why not convert it into an associative array? But if you must:

```
foreach($item as $x) {
  list($name, $val) = explode('=', $x, 2);
  $$name = $val;
}
```

Comment: or use a JSON...

also, how'll your code know ahead which variables were created and how to use them

Comment: @kishu27: How does the OP know that?  This is what the OP wanted.  How he wants to use them is up to him.

Comment: @kishu27 A JSON would be one big string, that doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: @kishu27 if OP wants to output data as it is shown in question just replace `$$name = $val;` with `echo $name . "=" . $val . "<br>";`

Comment: @RocketHazmat understood but lets say string comes with a monkey=9 and he didn't code for using a $monkey, it doesn't solve the purpose.  associative array makes much more sense and OP can loop through it to find both variable names and value.  of course there can be a 100 examples of what OP wants is a good idea, but with the data provided I guess Assoc Arrays are a better design.  just my thought :)

Comment: @Barmar I should have commented in more detail, i'm sorry.  I meant that he could use JSON strings in place of the string that he is showing and convert it to Assoc Arrays and use.  My vote goes to Assoc arrays and I wrote a supporting statement for that.  should've added more details to my comment :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try to join the array and parse the string into variables

```
parse_str(implode('&',$item));
```

Comment: Hmm, convert it into a query string, and parse it?  Clever :-)

Comment: Unless the values contain `&` characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$item[0] = "apple=5";
$item[1] = "banana=7";
$item[2] = "orange=8";


foreach($item as $row)
{
    $new    =   explode('=',$row);
    $array[$new[0]] =   $new[1];
}

extract($array);
echo $apple;
echo $banana;
echo $orange;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array looks like someone exploded an ini file on its newlines.

Implode with newlines, then parse, then call `extract()` to generate the variables. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jj0SO))

```
extract(
    parse_ini_string(
        implode(PHP_EOL, $item)
    )
);

echo "$apple $banana $orange";
```

Using `explode()` or `parse_ini_string()` or `preg_` functions (etc.) will render the numeric values as string-type.

If you'd like the numeric values to be integer-typed, then using `%d` in the "format" parameter of `sscanf()` will be most direct. ([Demo1](https://3v4l.org/7Wd6T))

```
foreach ($item as $string) {
    [$key, $$key] = sscanf($string, '%[^=]=%d');
}
```

---

Generally speaking, I do not advise the generation of individual variable (I more strenuously advise against variable variables). Perhaps an associative array would be suitable. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eeQos))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($item as $string) {
    [$key, $result[$key]] = sscanf($string, '%[^=]=%d');
}
var_dump($result);
```